# Suddenly getting "Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_LDR_MISMATCH_NATIVE)"

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

```
Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_LDR_MISMATCH_NATIVE)
```

My VMs on Virtualbox 4.2 (on Windows 7 32-bit) were running absolutely fine until I started installing a new VM, which would not go beyond the Linux boot screen.

I deleted the VM and created new one, but it still didn't run.

So I installed the new version of VirtualBox (version 4.3.6.r91406) and rebooted the machine; but when I started any of my previously working VMs, I got the following error

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine m14
Failed to load VMMR0.r0
(VERR_LDR_MISMATCH_NATIVE
```

with the following details:

```
Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole
{8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}
```

On checking the forums, I saw few posts asking to check the `.vbox` files. In the directory of the VM, there are two, `m14.vbox` and `m14.vbox-prev`.

I removed the prev file and restarted the VM, again got same error, and the `m14.vbox-prev` file came again. So I then removed the original `m14.vbox` file and renamed the prev file to original and then started the VM: it still didn't work.

Any clues fixing this?

Comment: joke from a movie: "PC LOAD LETTER!?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add or update the extension pack.

If that doesn't solves the problem, then uninstall the Virtual Box, delete the following folder:

```
C:\USERS\<username>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\Oracle
```

then install Virtual Box again and run it as administrator. (In some cases running it as simple user may work too.)

Comment: I am having the same problem with windows 8.1. The problem started happening all of a sudden. No matter what I try, I am unable to resolve the problem. I have tried re-installing it several times with whatever combination I could think of with no success. Anyway, you can provide additional info on how I can debug this further?

Comment: I found out the problem. I had driver verifier running in windows. Once I disabled it and restarted the computer, the error went away.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me on Windows 10 after upgrading from VB 5.0.1 to 5.0.2 -- sensible regardless since Windows 10 support is still firming up; but it is strange that the VM worked just fine a week ago with 5.0.1; and I have never had to install the extension pack previously. :/

Comment: This worked for me! Turns out the version of virtualbox i was running was slightly older than the version that the extension pack i installed was shipped with. Installing the older version from the [older builds](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds) page and installing it over top f the newer one gave me a neat little prompt to downgrade.

Answer (score 15):

Hi I had the same problem in version 4.3
I disabled the floppy and the CD into the system configuration of the virtual machine and then the machine has started properly without realizing the error.

[image]

Comment: As this link might answer the question, it's better for you to explain it here. Please refer on how to to make a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Works for me in Windows 10; it even still used the iso i selected as a CD! Er, until it kernel panicked about a bad EIP value.

Answer (score 6):

Run as Administrator

---

I had the same problem after updating from 4.1 or 4.2, to 4.3.18.

I didn't reboot and the "Right click Virtualbox icon - Run as Administrator" technique worked for me (in Windows).

Comment: Running VirtualBox as admin also works for me, but it is not an acceptable solution for me. Instead, uninstalling / reinstalling VirtualBox as administrator made the trick.

Answer (score 1):

pls run the vbox-ssl-cacertificate.crt file. That may resolve above problem. This solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY.

A while back I turned on ASLR for everything using EMET. Running EMET again and changing it back to the default of "Application OptIn" + reboot fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Like akshah123 I had driver verifier (verifier.exe) running because I was diagnosing random BSODs on my laptop.  Running:

```
verifier.exe /reset
```

and then rebooting fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Launching VirtualBox as administrator got my VM running as normal.

Didn't need to try any other approach.